# UIWebView Stops Entire App When Double Tap

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an iOS app that stops responding if a user double clicks any link in the UIWebView.  I have no output in the log when this happens, it just stops responding.  I'm not sure how to debug, or get any more information from this problem.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can proceed?  I vaguely remember this being an endless loop glitch within UIWebView from an earlier app I created, however I cannot find any record of this online or in the latest XCode.

If anyone has advice as to where I can pull data from to help identify the problem, I would be very appreciative.  So far I've monitored NSLog output and the crash logs on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

All of the JavaScript and actions taken by a UIWebView occur on the main thread; which is probably causing the hanging behavior.

I would assign a class to the the delegate of the UIWebView and implement the 'webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:' method of the delegate. This method gets called on each request made by the UIWebView. Logging within this can show you what AJAX calls or other resource calls are being made by the web app.

Comment: Will look into that method.  I may add that I stripped the html page to the most basic with no javascript, only a single <a href=""> link and if I double tap it still stops the whole app.  Only way to recover functionality is a force quit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to review my answer. it may help you.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href=\"http://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Google Link\" 
            name=\"Google\">http://www.google.com</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

i have added link "www.google.com" in html string. Now When user click on the link it will open into iPhone default browser.

Don't forget to add UIWebview Delegate Method in you Code.

Comment: This does not help as part of the app requires embedded UIWebView...  I need to know how to troubleshoot the issue I have rather than circumvent it by sending the user to another app.  Thanks, anyway!